# DeleteTimerQueueTimer() access violation and/or deadlock

Tags: c++, windows, visual-c++, windows-7-x64

Second DeleteTimerQueueTimer() generates access violation, or invalid parameter exception, or hangs indefinetely, depending on context. Google test code:

```
HANDLE hTimer = NULL;

static VOID CALLBACK _TimerCallback(PVOID, BOOLEAN)
{
    //::DeleteTimerQueueTimer(NULL, hTimer, NULL);
}

TEST(CTest, TimerQueue)
{
    ASSERT_EQ(FALSE, ::DeleteTimerQueueTimer(NULL, hTimer, NULL));
    ASSERT_EQ(TRUE, ::CreateTimerQueueTimer(&hTimer, NULL, &_TimerCallback, NULL, 40, 0, WT_EXECUTEONLYONCE));
    ASSERT_TRUE(NULL != hTimer);
    Sleep(100);
    ASSERT_EQ(TRUE, ::DeleteTimerQueueTimer(NULL, hTimer, NULL));
    // ******** next line produces SEH or deadlocks *************
    ASSERT_EQ(FALSE, ::DeleteTimerQueueTimer(NULL, hTimer, NULL)); 
}
```

[ RUN      ] CTest.TimerQueue
unknown file: error: SEH exception with code 0xc000000d thrown in the test body.

Comment: So I have to guard the call:  static BOOL DeleteTimer(HANDLE hTimer)
{
 __try {
  return ::DeleteTimerQueueTimer(NULL, hTimer, NULL);
 } __except(EXCEPTION_EXECUTE_HANDLER) {
 }
 return FALSE;
}

Comment: Guarding the call is not a solution.  There's no guarantee that the result of deleting an already-deleted handle will be an exception.  The OS might simply terminate the program out of hand, and is entitled to do so.

Answer (score 2):

[MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms682569%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) says: "Timer [in]: A handle to the timer-queue timer. This handle is returned by the CreateTimerQueueTimer function."

You are calling `DeleteTimerQueueTimer` twice for the same `hTimer`. So in the second call to `DeleteTimerQueueTimer` you are not adhering to the function specification because you are passing some invalid `HANDLE`. Windows might (in my opinion *should*) handle that in a better way than with an SEH or hanging but: *garbage in, garbage out*.

Comment: No, I don't expect it to succeed. Just a copy-paste. I don't expect it to crash or hang the program

Comment: What is ASSERT_EQ doing? Is it part of some testing framework? Is ASSERT_EQ throwing the SEH exception?

Comment: No, it just checks for equality.

Comment: As I said, you are calling DeleteTimerQueueTimer with an invalid handle. Fix that bug and the program won't hang or crash. Regarding your assumptions I updated my answer.

Comment: It's not a bug, it's a feature. Timers are async, thus it's normal to call those functions twice. @Garbage out@ would be returning FALSE, not shooting the process in the foot.

Comment: @user1636138: It is *not* normal to call DeleteTimerQueueTimer multiple times for the same handle. Windows might see the handle as a pointer to some Memory, if you are using that handle after it is closed, every Windows function you pass that handle to might access freed memory and thus crash. If you call functions like DeleteTimerQueueTimer, CloseHandle, GlobalFree, LocalFree, ... multiple times, then learn to program in a clean and robust way. EOD.

Comment: Sure, calling a pointer a handle, and reusing randomly picked typedef for that purpose is "a clean and robust way". Thanks.

Comment: also the handle is free after you delete it the first time, it could theoretically be reassigned by windows to something else before you delete it the second time.

Comment: @OlegB: handles are opaque (that is, the meaning of any particular value is undefined) so the API is perfectly entitled to use any value it finds convenient, including a pointer.  It doesn't make sense to expose the implementation details to the programmer, because they might need to change: a handle that is actually a pointer in Windows XP might be an index in Windows Vista, or vice-versa.  This has to be transparent to the programmer, so a single typedef is used.